# Как в массиве с объектами записать в подмассивы объекты, в которых совпадают значения свойств?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть такой массив объектов:

```
[ 
  {"ind": 1, "nes": 0}, 
  {"ind": 2, "nes": 1}, 
  {"ind": 3, "nes": 1}, 
  {"ind": 4, "nes": 1}, 
  {"ind": 5, "nes": 1}, 
  {"ind": 6, "nes": 2}, 
  {"ind": 7, "nes": 2}, 
  {"ind": 8, "nes": 2}, 
  {"ind": 9, "nes": 3}, 
  {"ind": 10, "nes": 3}, 
  {"ind": 11, "nes": 4}, 
  {"ind": 12, "nes": 4}, 
  {"ind": 13, "nes": 4}
]
```

Как собрать в подмассивы все объекты с одинаковым `nes`, чтобы получилось так:

```
[ 
  {"ind": 1, "nes": 0}, 
  [
    {"ind": 2, "nes": 1}, 
    {"ind": 3, "nes": 1}, 
    {"ind": 4, "nes": 1}
  ],
  {"ind": 5, "nes": 1}, 
  [
    {"ind": 6, "nes": 2}, 
    {"ind": 7, "nes": 2}, 
    {"ind": 8, "nes": 2}
  ], 
  {"ind": 9, "nes": 3}, 
  [
    {"ind": 10, "nes": 4}, 
    {"ind": 11, "nes": 4}, 
    {"ind": 12, "nes": 4}, 
    {"ind": 13, "nes": 4}
  ],
]
```

Если св-во `nes` в объекте нет, или нет его повторений, позиция объекта не меняется. Желательно понятный способ, который будет работать в самом последнем ie, но это не обязательно.

Comment: `{"ind": 5, "nes": 1}, ` не попало в группу по ошибке?

Comment: да, извиняюсь за это

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gb5cm4tx/

Comment: Спасибо Вам, это работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это как я показал в примере

```js
var arr = [ 
    {"ind": 1, "nes": 0}, 
    {"ind": 2, "nes": 1}, 
    {"ind": 3, "nes": 1}, 
    {"ind": 4, "nes": 1}, 
    {"ind": 5, "nes": 1}, 
    {"ind": 6, "nes": 2}, 
    {"ind": 7, "nes": 2}, 
    {"ind": 8, "nes": 2}, 
    {"ind": 9, "nes": 3}, 
    {"ind": 10, "nes": 3}, 
    {"ind": 11, "nes": 4}, 
    {"ind": 12, "nes": 4}, 
    {"ind": 13, "nes": 4}
];

var groups = {};
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];

    if(!groups[item.nes]) {
        groups[item.nes] = [];
    }

    groups[item.nes].push(item);
}

var res = [];

for(var group in groups) {
    if(!groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) {
        continue;
    }

    if(groups[group].length === 1) {
        res.push(groups[group][0]);
    } else {
        res.push(groups[group]);
    }
}

console.log(res);
```